# Sails-mongo automatic failover

Tags: mongodb, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm using sails-mongo in my nodejs application, and my config looks like this:

```
mongoDb: {
adapter: 'sails-mongo',
url: 'mongodb://prod_user:prod_password@router-1-incloud:16888,router-2-incloud:16888/db_name',
auto_reconnect: true,
poolSize: parseInt(process.env.MONGO_POOL_LIMIT) || 10,
w: parseInt(process.env.MONGO_WRITE_CONCERT_INT) || 'majority',
reconnectInterval: 200,
wtimeout: parseInt(process.env.MONGO_WRITE_TIMEOUT_MS) || 2000,
retryMiliSeconds: 200,
numberOfRetries: 3,
readPreference: process.env.MONGO_READ_PREFERENCE || 'primaryPreferred',
socketOptions: {
  noDelay: true,
  keepAlive: 0,
  connectTimeoutMS: parseInt(process.env.MONGO_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS) || 2000,
  socketTimeoutMS: parseInt(process.env.MONGO_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS) || 2000
}
```

So when `router-1-incloud:16888` goes down driver doesn't switch to `router-2-incloud:16888` even when I restart my application, it always needs both routers to be available or it won't establish connection to mongo. Is there a config value I need to adjust so it automatically switches to any available host?

Comment: how many members are there in replica set? What error does is show when router-1-incloud:16888 goes down?

Comment: @Astro the error in node is `MongoError: server router-1-incloud:16888 sockets closed` and it's 2 routers and 2 replicas.